# Partial Renderer OpenGL (viewport) on QT QQuickWindow

Tags: qt, opengl

How to render OpenGL viewport on QT Window? Even if I set `glViewport(100, 100, 100, 100)`, it renders in all window. I want show partial view for Opengl and partial view for QT Controls. 
I am using QT5 + QML (QQuickWindow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml) specifies the transformation of normalized device coordinates to window coordinates. But it doesn't "protect" the framebuffer area, outside a certain rectangle, from being written to.
So it doesn't effect operations like `glClear`.

The [Scissor Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Scissor_Test) can be used to define a rectangle and discards operation on fragments which are not inside the rectangle.
The scissor test has to be enabled by [`glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnable.xhtml) and the rectangular scissor area can be defined by [`glScissor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glScissor.xhtml):

e.g.

```
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glScissor(100, 100, 100, 100);
```